# How can i stop React-router-dom throwing up blank screens

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-dom

This is the brief snippet from Nav.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Logo from '../Pic_resources/logo_2.jpg';
import '../CSS_build/Navbar.css';

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
      <h1>Beta_testing program for react_JS</h1>
      <div className='left_side'>
        <img src={Logo} alt='' />
      </div>
      <div>  
        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>   
        <Link to='/About'>About</Link>
        <Link to='/Explore'>Explore</Link>
        <Link to='/Contact'>Contact</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../CSS_build/Home.css';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='home'>
      <h2>Testing_using React-router dom</h2>
      <p>A tiny VS Code extension made up of a few commands
        that generate and insert lorem ipsum text into a text file.
        To use the extension, open the command palette 
        F1 or cmd/ctrl+shift+p, type "lorem ipsum" an
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Js_component/Navbar';
import Home from './Js_component/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route index path='/' element={<Navbar />} />
          <Route path='/Home' element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route index path='/*' Component={<App />} />
    </Routes>  
  </Router>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I have redone the whole code lines many times. If I remove the react router import statement and try to render the code block it renders but when I correctly imports it and write the necessary routing statements, the screen renders blank.

Comment: Are the "blank screens" just the URL paths you are linking to that don't have routes defined for them? Can you [edit] to provide more details regarding this issue? What version of `react-router-dom` have you installed?

Comment: i have react router dom v 6

Comment: Sorry, I meant what *specific* version of `react-router-dom` are you using. The `Route` component's `Component` prop was introduced more recently and really only works with using a data router that was introduced in v6.4. You don't need that route in `index.js` though. Has my answer below helped address/resolve your question/issue?

Answer (score 0):

Without copy/pasting your code into a running sandbox to verify I suspect your issue is with the `<Route index path='/*' Component={<App />} />` route in the `index.js` file. The `index` prop likely takes priority over the `path` prop (*you never need both, it's **always** one or the other*) and so none of the descendent routes that `App` is rendering can be matched and rendered.

The good news is that this route is ***entirely*** unnecessary. You can just render `App` directly.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App /> 
  </Router>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

You also need only one router per app to provide the routing context. Remove the `Router` that `App` is rendering. You will want to also render routes for the other paths you are linking to, and/or provide a "catch-all" fallback route to handle everything else.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Js_component/Navbar';
import Home from './Js_component/Home';
// ... other component imports ...

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/explore" element={<Explore />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```